# Can I use userstyles to add a font to ALL the font stacks in a page?

Tags: css, fonts

We use a script encoded in the PUA at E000-E1FF.  It's not supported by any commercial fonts, but we have fonts for it.  The trick is getting pages like Gmail, Facebook, Reddit, WhatsApp Web, etc. to use one of our installed fonts to display the text.

If we know the selectors for the element(s) where text is displayed, and the list of existing fonts in the stack, then we can use Stylus to override the font-family style with an updated list, adding one of our fonts.

But it would be better to use the preprocessor simply to add our font to every font-family style declaration, if possible.

How might we do that?  Or is there an even better solution?

Comment: You want to use a preprocessor to control the appearance of text in pages outside your control?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do.